# "Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for module..."

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, intellij-13

I have a very simple Java + Gradle project. It builds fine. It runs fine from the shell with "gradle run". However, if I try to run inside of IntelliJ, I get:

```
Cannot start compilation: the output path is not specified for module "xyz" Specify the output path in Configure Project.
```

My "Compiler output" is set to "Inherit project compile output path". I don't want a custom output path, whatever that is, just do a normal gradle build and run.

Comment: When running code from IntelliJ, it will be compiled and run by IntelliJ rather than Gradle, and a different build output directory will be used. (Android is a different story.) However, if the Gradle build is imported correctly, the IntelliJ output directory should already be configured.

Comment: On the answers below, be careful to give a path in which you have user permission to write, or else it won't work.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You just have to go to your `Module settings > Project` and specify a "Project compiler output" and make your modules inherit from project. (For that go to `Modules > Paths > Inherit project`.

This did the trick for me.

Comment: Well, not choosing the `Inherit Project` option worked for me

Comment: Why can it not figure this out for itself. Everyone says IntelliJ is better than Eclipse but in my experience, it can't think for itself.

Comment: FYI, I've found that in IntelliJ you do a File > New > Module... and create a Java module, the output path should get set by default.

Comment: If this doesn't appear to work, don't forget to restart IntelliJ. Fixed it for me.

Answer (score 137):

You have to define a *path* in the "**Project compiler output**" field in

> `File` > `Project Structure...` > `Project` > `Project compiler output`

[image]

This path will be used to store all project *compilation results*.

Answer (score 24):

I'm answering this so that I can find the solution when I have to google this error again.

Set project compile output path to `path_of_the_project_folder/out`. That's what is working today.
The intellj documentation makes it seem like we can select any folder but that's not the case.

Answer (score 13):

If none of the above method worked then try this it worked for me.

Go to *File > Project Structure> Project* and then in *Project Compiler Output* click on the three dots and provide the path of your project name(name of the file) and then click on *Apply* and than on *Ok*.

Comment: There is no picture in your answer.

Comment: @priyanshu : Seriously, there is no picture, in your post.

Answer (score 12):

While configuring idea plugin in gradle, you should define output directories as follows.

```
idea{
    module{
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = compileJava.destinationDir
        testOutputDir = compileTestJava.destinationDir
    }
}
```

Comment: looks great. What file do I put this configuration in?

Comment: You should put it to build.gradle file in your project.

Answer (score 5):

Open .iml file.
Look for keyword 'NewModuleRootManager'. Check if attribute 'inherit-compiler-output' is set to true or not. If not set to true.

Like this :

```
component name="NewModuleRootManager" inherit-compiler-output="true">
    <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/test" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/spec" isTestSource="true" />
      <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/app" isTestSource="false" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Two things to do:

1. Project Settings > [Project compiler output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMDiE.png) > Set it as "Project path(You actual project's path)”+”\out”.
2. Project Settings > Module > Path > Choose "[Inherit project compile path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahOqC.png)"

Answer (score 4):

After this

Two things to do:

> Project Settings > Project compiler output > Set it as "Project
> path(You actual project's path)”+”\out”.
>
> Project Settings > Module > Path > Choose "Inherit project compile
> path""

If button ran is not active

You must reload  IDEA

Answer (score 1):

I get this error too when creating a project in IntelliJ without using a template.

I have 2 SDKs installed: Amazon Corretto and java version 11.0.4 
and so, what I do when I have this error is "change the SDK" it usually works fine with Corretto

to do that you need to click on File (in IntelliJ)/ Project Structure / Project / Project SDK: select corretto from the dropdown list (or check the option in your computer) as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQMIz.png)

hope this will work for you too

Best,
Constantin

Answer (score 1):

Bugs caused by missing predefined folder for store compiled class file which is normally is /out folder by default. You can give a try to close Intellij > Import Project > From existing source. This will solve this problem.

Comment: This is what finally fixed my issue

Answer (score 1):

Change the Path of  the Compile Output Path inside File > Project Structure > Modules > Paths

- Check the Use module compile output path
- Inside Output Path, set the output path as /target/classes.
  e.g. - S:\myProjectFolder\myProject\target\classes

This worked for me. Don't forget to clean install your project once.
If it doesn't work, make sure you restart Intellij once.

Answer (score 0):

None of the suggestions worked for me until I ran the command "gradle cleanIdeaModule ideaModule" info here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html

Answer (score 0):

change drop down to start file your project

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing this for a module that you have added using Gradle's new test suites feature, it can be because the module settings show screen it is *not* using inheritOutputDirs. Although you can fix the issue by changing the setting there, you are correctly warned that it will revert next time the gradle sync runs.

Instead you can force all modules to use inherit with:

```
idea {
  module {
    inheritOutputDirs true
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete `.idea` folder -> restart IntelliJ --> set the project again.

Comment: Only causes more problem.