# Cannot start compilation error from git project

Tags: java, github, intellij-idea

When I try to import project from github to Intellij Idea, it succesfully getting.

I want to run it and see the output. But **when I compile it, I get the error** `cannot start compilation`.

Here is the picture of my [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ror7A.png).

As I understand from the error, the **output directory** is not exist.

I use Project Structure --> Project compiler output to initialize it.

I described it as `projectname\out`. Also my `compiler output` is set to `Inherit project compile output path`.

**Then I rebuild my project but it doesn't success**.

I just want to run github project in Intellij Idea.

Comment: Have you checked this previous solution?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23688702/cannot-start-compilation-the-output-path-is-not-specified-for-module

Comment: Yes I checked  this solution but it didn't work for me.

Comment: Does your project use Maven or Gradle? `Then I rebuild my project but it doesn't success.` - what error do you see when you rebuild with output directory specified?

Comment: It uses Gradle. When I rebuilt it and try to run, nothing happens and there is no error message.