# Error connecting to SQ Server from Java: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I am using this code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class ConnectMSSQLServer
{
    public void dbConnect(String db_connect_string, String db_userid, String db_password)
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);
            System.out.println("connected");
            Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
            String queryString = "select * from sysobjects where type='u'";
            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString(1));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConnectMSSQLServer connServer = new ConnectMSSQLServer();
        connServer.dbConnect("jdbc:sqlserver://C1A\\SQL1A", "P", "G31les");
    }
}
```

But I get this error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java" -Didea.launcher.port=7532 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\charsets.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\deploy.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\access-bridge-64.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\cldrdata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jaccess.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\jfxrt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\nashorn.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunec.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\ext\zipfs.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\javaws.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jce.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jfr.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jfxswt.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\jsse.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\management-agent.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\plugin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\resources.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\jre\lib\rt.jar;C:\Users\wmoscoso\Desktop\SaturnLittleBrother\out\production\SaturnLittleBrother;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2016.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain ConnectMSSQLServer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at ConnectMSSQLServer.dbConnect(ConnectMSSQLServer.java:16)
    at ConnectMSSQLServer.main(ConnectMSSQLServer.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am new to Java, could somebody point me in the right direction? I don't know how to set a class path is that is needed? why do I even need to do that?

Comment: You're missing the top (and most important) part of your error message. If I had to guess, I'd say the your JDBC jar is not in your classpath.

Comment: The JVM can't find the class `SaturnDBInterface`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300318/error-classnotfoundexception-in-intellij-idea) might help

Comment: Why are you trying to run a class called `SaturnDBInterface` when your class is called `ConnectMSSQLServer`? You should check the run descriptor (or whatever it's called in IntelliJ) that you're using to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. I need to download the jar files for a JDBC connection from the Microsoft website and then added them to my project.