# Error "class not found" in IntelliJ ide on mac

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea

I am currently running the latest IntelliJ on mac os el capitan.

I have built a project and it builds successfully, however when I try to run it I get the following message:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.company.Main
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:123)

 Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have looked at this question [Error "ClassNotFoundException" in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300318/error-classnotfoundexception-in-intellij-idea) however none of the answers there worked.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you have a directory `com/company` and a `Main.java` file in there?

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer   nope, my structure is com/wyre/timebackup

Comment: @JochenBedersdorfer how do i tell intelliJ that my structure is different then what they think it is?, In other words how do i change the settings?

Comment: Then check the package name in `Main.java`. It needs to be `package com.wyre.timebackup`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might not know it, but when you run your program from within IntelliJ IDEA, you are making use of a Run/Debug Configuration to do that.  IntelliJ IDEA keeps important information about how to run your program in these Run/Debug Configurations.  If your program does not start, it is most likely due to a Run/Debug Configuration misconfiguration.

Edit your Run/Debug Configurations, find the Run/Debug Configuration that you are currently using, and look at the "Main class:" field.  You will find that it is "com.company.SomeClass".  Replace that with the full name of your main class.  Your main class is the class with your `main()` function.

Alternatively, find the class that contains your `main()` function, open up a context menu on that class, and select 'Run' or 'Debug'. This will create a new Run/Debug configuration for it.

If the newly created Run/Debug configuration is not working, open up the Run/Debug Configuration Dialog and compare your newly created Run/Debug configuration against the old one, there may be some additional setting that needs to be copied from the old to the new.

The Run/Debug Configuration Dialog can be found by selecting "Edit configurations..." from the Run/Debug Configuration Drop Down List.

The Run/Debug Configuration Drop Down List can be found on the main toolbar of IntelliJ IDEA.  (Normally, it is the only drop-down list on the toolbar.)

Comment: Under which category is the configuration settings?

Comment: There should be a drop-down list in the toolbar across the top of the IntelliJ IDEA window.  It is the only drop-down list.