# IntelliJ unable to run: main class not found. Terminal runs the class just fine

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea

After extensive research through Google, Stackoverflow and peers I am still unable to solve the below stated issue.

IntelliJ is unable to locate any main class of whatever file I choose:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class nl.sam.inventory.InventoryApplication
```

I have followed the answer which was posted on SO: [Error "ClassNotFoundException" in IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300318/error-classnotfoundexception-in-intellij-idea)

My main class:

```
package nl.sam.inventory;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class InventoryApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(InventoryApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

My run settings are left as default (IntelliJ picked these up).

My project structure:
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0T0yt.png)

If I left anything out please state so.

I have verified I have a JRE (11) and JDK (11) installed and working on my machine. In a terminal the program runs just fine: in IntelliJ I get the aforementioned error.

Edit: I use Maven for project management. A project without maven shows the same behaviour.

Comment: possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654120/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-intellij-ide

Comment: This means that your project wasn't successfully imported into IntelliJ or it wasn't rebuild before you attempted to run.

Comment: @MustafaÇil I have tried the answers of that question too: no result.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki the project was created through IntelliJ. After a rebuild it still does the same.

Comment: Created or imported? If you are using external build tool like Maven you are suppose to import, not create new project from scratch.

Comment: Check build path. Make sure the package is there in the build path of the project settings.. Or try this
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000156824-How-to-choose-main-class

Comment: @KarolDowbecki1 I used the "Create project" from the splash screen of IntelliJ. It created the project for me. I also tried a console application through the template given by IntelliJ with the same result.

Comment: @A_01 I have tried the answers given in your link. It didn't work unfortunately

Comment: Are you using Maven to define your project?

Comment: Please specify your build type. It is maven, it is gradle, or?

Comment: I'm using the default options given by IntelliJ. It's through Maven, yes.

Comment: Most likely your source file exists outside of a designated source directory.

Comment: I have seen this answer in a different question: I can verify that this is not the case. The file exists in the src/ folder.

Comment: There could be many reasons for this error, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891 for some. If the issue persists, please submit a ticket at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/requests/new with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085) attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused by something not yet described before. My path had a space in it, which my MacBook turned into a :. Due to this the main class could never be found. I've changed my username to not contain a space, and it now works just fine.

Comment: This case is already mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/42660624/104891.