# Main method not found on IntelliJ "Run"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, main-method

I have just started with Codename One. I have managed to successfully run the "Get started" app on NetBeans, but decided to work on IntelliJ IDE for future development.
Followed all instructions and installed Codename One for IntelliJ. When I "Run" the "Get Started" app, a ClassNotFoundException is thrown. The problem relates to the Main method. Any tips?

Comment: You can have a refer here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300318/error-classnotfoundexception-in-intellij-idea)

Comment: Thank you @dev for the quick reply. My problem is solved now. However, I managed to do so independently, since the solution checked as valid was not applicable to the current user interface of IntelliJ. Still though thanks.